# ExcelDnaUtility.Application creating a new book (Book1), so first new book in excel is Book2

Tags: c#, excel, appdomain, excel-dna

I have a C# ExcelDna project that, in general, has no issues.  However, I use ExcelDna.Application to open a spreadsheet during AutoOpen() (an xlam).   I noticed that the first "USER CREATED" workbook, using Excel Menus is Book2.  To isolate this, I did the code below.  Even when not opening any workbooks, just referring to ExcelDna.Application seems to create a shadow workbook that moves the workbook counter to Book2.   Is this a known thing, a bug? or something I'm doing wrong!  Thanks/Cheers

```cs
public class ExcelDNAXllEntry : IExcelAddIn
  {
      public void AutoOpen()
      {
          // EXCEL DNA  STUFF ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
          ComServer.DllRegisterServer();
          //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          Application x = (Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
```

I'd expect the first user opened book to be book1.  There are no hard errors or error messages, just the odd behavior that I'd like to avoid.  We have many users and if they start seeing Book2 I'll be answering lots of questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Excel loads your add-in, the COM object model is (typically) not yet initialised. I know of no other way to get Excel into a state where we can get to the Application COM object, other than by creating a new 'macro' type workbook behind the scenes. A consequence is the behaviour you report.

I'd be very happy to incorporate an alternative approach in Excel-DNA.

Comment: Thanks Govert, and that's kind of what I was expecting.   I guess the easy follow-up question is - do you have any suggestions for opening a workbook as part of the launching of the xll add-in that might avoid the book pointer issue?    I've been playing with an async process on the same (main) thread, so I can get ExcelDnaUtilitie's Application object after its in the correct state.  I might be getting close, OR it might be impossible! Thanks in advance for any more ideas!

Comment: And - I'm intrigued by "I'd be very happy to incorporate an alternative approach in Excel-DNA."   Can you expand on that?

Comment: It's been a while since I looked at this, but the problem might not go away just because a workbook is created or opened. So just waiting might not be good enough, unless other (COM) add-ins or some VBA code is present. 
In some cases Excel-DNA itself gets the Application object (e.g. when showing a ribbon). So even your workaround might not work without some changes to Excel-DNA itself.

Comment: You can certainly try stuff - the minor cosmetic issue has not really been an issue so far. Users ask once because they're curious, not because it really bothers them or they somehow rely on the name of the first blank book. There might still be some magic trick that gets Excel to initialize the COM object model without create the new book - I just don't know one.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by

1. Adding first line in AutoOpen()

   ```
   bool create = (bool)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcNew, 1);
   ```
2. In ribbon OnLoad(IRibbonUI ribbon)

   ```
   excel = (Excel.Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;

   XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFileClose, false);
   ```

First step ensure that ExcelDna.Integration/Excel.cs will not use GetApplicationFromNewWorkbook. Second argument 1 in XlCall.Excel means that "Sheet1" is internally created, not "Book1"

The second step closes its own in order to not show empty "Sheet1" window.
Now counting starts from Book1,Book2...

I tested it on Office365, Excel 2106 and Excel 2013, all x64 and it works.

Comment: That worked for me.  Awesome...  have tried a bunch of stuff before re-checking stack and finding this.  Appreciate the post